PHPIMAP How to detect and parent reply message in helpdesk

System - helpdesk
Gmail
Codeigniter 4
Library PHPIMAP
PHPMAILER

From GMAIL i sent new message to system and retrive message_id
$messageIdAttribute = $attributes['message_id']; // Access the message_id attribute
$messageId = $messageIdAttribute->first(); // Get the first value
var_dump($messageId); // Output the message ID
string(66) "CAMpA-USiPhhMEy_iNGvQBru_pZ2d_cu3nE7WQOR84xGXZUvqfg@mail.gmail.com"

From SYSTEM i sent reply to this message and set in   header main message id (generated by gmail) in reply to
// Set the In-Reply-To header with the original message ID
 $messageId = $originalEmail['message_id'];  
if ($messageId) {
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $messageId);
}

Now i check in gmail, and is correct parent my reply from system to gmail. So now I again send reply from gmail to system and again var dump headers/ attributes / references in reply to etc.
and each values is totally different and is not possible anyway parent this last reply message to main message.
["references"]=>
  object(Webklex\PHPIMAP\Attribute)#64 (2) {
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(10) "references"
    ["values":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(59) "T30MUQOUSh7HsvtKUC2TUgQwsBWsEHLxoaldeHejDXY@api.app***.com"
    }
  }
  ["message_id"]=>
  object(Webklex\PHPIMAP\Attribute)#65 (2) {
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(10) "message_id"
    ["values":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(66) "CAMpA-USUQxnnb=NesKhYd6=iRV6p_W3hT0vKh1EULLjrd8TV=w@mail.gmail.com"
    }
  }
  ["in_reply_to"]=>
  object(Webklex\PHPIMAP\Attribute)#66 (2) {
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(11) "in_reply_to"
    ["values":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(59) "T30MUQOUSh7HsvtKUC2TUgQwsBWsEHLxoaldeHejDXY@api.app****.com"
    }
  }

How to correct parent replies?
